# Can't pip install javabridge

Tags: java, python, pip

Ubuntu 18.04, python 2.7

I try

```
sudo pip install javabridge
```

I get

```
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-voWMrv/javabridge/setup.py", line 396, in <module>
    ext_modules=ext_modules(),
  File "/tmp/pip-install-voWMrv/javabridge/setup.py", line 131, in ext_modules
    library_dirs = [os.path.dirname(jvm_so)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 122, in dirname
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-voWMrv/javabridge/

I was able to do

```
sudo pip install javabridge==1.0.16
```

But it turns out that I need the newest one, 1.0.17, for which I still get the error above.

This command

```
find /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 -type f -name "*jvm.so"
```

Gives

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so
```

Then I ran

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
~$ JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Finally

```
sudo pip install javabridge --user myName
```

Gives the same error

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-i61jKx/javabridge/setup.py", line 396, in <module>
        ext_modules=ext_modules(),
      File "/tmp/pip-install-i61jKx/javabridge/setup.py", line 131, in ext_modules
        library_dirs = [os.path.dirname(jvm_so)]
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 122, in dirname
        i = p.rfind('/') + 1
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

I also tried

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 pip install javabridge --user

Collecting javabridge
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/87/0b016838c2a33b46b8775a3890150c93507931127cf62e9ccf27ac20db34/javabridge-1.0.17.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-QDCLar/javabridge/setup.py", line 396, in <module>
        ext_modules=ext_modules(),
      File "/tmp/pip-install-QDCLar/javabridge/setup.py", line 131, in ext_modules
        library_dirs = [os.path.dirname(jvm_so)]
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 122, in dirname
        i = p.rfind('/') + 1
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: You're missing `javac`, the Java compiler. Install JDK: `apt install default-jdk`.

Comment: Thanks. I do have ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/, is your advice still applicable?

Comment: Most probably that's just the JRE (Java runtime environment) which is not enough.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, now getting different error. Please see edit above. Should I do something like this maybe,and what path do I use?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

Comment: Sure, you need to set up JDK so it is usable. Test whether things work by issuing `printf 'import java.lang.*; public class Test {public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println("Hello world");}}' > Test.java && javac Test.java && java Test && rm Test.*`, you should get `Hello world` printed.

Comment: I do, yes, that worked.

Comment: So you set `JAVA_HOME`, but the error with `javabridge` still remains?

Comment: I do not have JAVA_HOME, what exactly and how do I set it? I thought it was not right originally, so I got rid of it, can you please tell me details on this

Comment: `update-alternatives --config java` should give you the path, among other things. Check whether `libjvm.so` is present in there: `find /path/to/jdk -type f -name "*jvm.so"`. Then try installing with `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk JDK_HOME=/path/to/jdk pip install javabridge --user`.

Comment: I made edits to the original question, please let me know if you have any ideas what should I try? Also, what exactly is my path to jdk, i.e. does it end with /bin/java, or before that? Please see above

Comment: The `/path/to/jdk/` should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` in your case. It's the root of JDK installation. `bin/java` is just the path to java executable.

Comment: I followed your instructions, please see the edits in the original question above. Still the same error.

Comment: That's because you ran the command wrong. Run it exactly as I wrote it, don't split it in two commands. And don't add stuff, there should be no `sudo` in it.

Comment: Same output, please see edits above

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in a fresh Ubuntu container, let me try it out.

Comment: Great, thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're running into [this issue](https://github.com/LeeKamentsky/python-javabridge/issues/137). `javabridge` package is not updated to changes in Java 9/10/11 regarding the restructuring of the JRE target dir (an intermediate dir named after the target arch removed), so you can only use the Java 8 at the moment. This is how I could install `javabridge` successfully in an `ubuntu:latest` docker container:

```
$ apt update
$ apt install software-properties-common
$ add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ apt install openjdk-8-jdk
$ update-alternatives --config java
```

This should give you the path to OpenJDK 8 similar to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`, remove the `jre/bin/java` suffix to get the JDK root.

Now install `javabridge`:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 pip install javabridge --user
Installing collected packages: javabridge
  Running setup.py install for javabridge ... done
Successfully installed javabridge-1.0.17
```

Comment: Getting
gpg: unknown option 'show-only'
gpg: invalid import options
Got '0' fingerprints, expected only one
Failed to add key.

Comment: Actually it worked, thanks. But I got it when trying to add the repository.

Comment: I'd say that's a topic for another question, as I'm not aware of GPG key management on Ubuntu. Best seek help on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

https://pythonhosted.org/javabridge/installation.html#dependencies:

The Javabridge requires Python 2.6 or above, NumPy, the Java Development Kit (JDK), and a C compiler.

```
sudo apt install python2.7 python-numpy openjdk-8-jdk gcc
```

Comment: I think I should have all those, do you have concrete advice, concrete command to run?

Comment: Please see above, I ran your command, and then getting another error with rfind.